# How to fix read access violation when push back to a vector pointer c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, graphics, new-operator

I'm having read access violation error when I try to push vec3 pointers to a vector. Below are my code and error message:

```
struct Mesh_Data
 {
     std::vector <glm::vec3*>* vertices;
     std::vector<glm::vec3*>* faces;
 };    

he::Mesh_Data* meshData = new he::Mesh_Data;
glm::vec3* test = glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);
meshData->faces->push_back(test); // program breaks on this line
```

error message:

****Exception thrown: read access violation.
**_My_data** was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE7. occurred****

May I ask how to fix it and what's the cause of this issue（if you have time to explain a bit about what happened on mechine that'll be so great!)

I guess it might be because the newly allocated meshData pointer hasn't been initialized. But in this case I'm not sure how to initialize it, I just want to add vec3 pointers to it.

Thank you.

Comment: meshData->faces is not initialized and it's being addressed as if it was a vector. you should create a class to properly construct Mesh_data objects

Comment: @Rafael thank you! I made it a class and constructed. Now it works. But I'm a bit uncertain about when to delete them as meshData is processed every frame when key is pressed.

Comment: if you *have* to use pointers, put some clothes on them; try to avoid the use of naked pointers. you can make those pointers "smart" by making them unique_ptrs or shared_ptrs and then you won't have to worry about that

Answer (score 3):

If you weren't using pointers your code would work. Why all the pointers?

```
struct Mesh_Data
{
    std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> faces;
};    

he::Mesh_Data meshData;
glm::vec3 test = glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);
meshData.faces.push_back(test);
```

Since the main purpose of `vector` is to avoid the complications of handling pointers, a pointer to a vector makes no sense at all. A vector of pointers sometimes makes sense, but even then you are generally better using a smart pointer instead of 'raw' pointers.

Comment: Thank you! But there are millions vertices on a mesh, Mesh_Data is to process all the points. Without using pointers there'll be a whole lot copy work to the vector. Is there a way to use pointers?

Comment: @EyezzeyE There are plenty of ways to avoid copying the vector - using references, moving instead of copying. That's what you should be concentrating on.

Comment: @EyezzeyE But of course `mashData = new Mash_Data(); mashData->faces = new std::vector<glm::vec3>(); mashData->faces->push_back(test);` is legal code. Just not very good code.

Comment: You could even disable copying in your `Mesh_Data` struct, to make sure you don't copy it 'accidentally'. `struct Mesh_Data
{
    std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> faces; Mesh_Data(const Mesh_Data&) = delete; Mesh_Data& operator=(const Mesh_Data&) = delete;
};`

Comment: THanks! I'd love to know why `mashData = new Mash_Data(); mashData->faces = new std::vector<glm::vec3>(); mashData->faces->push_back(test)` is not good code? (I'm fairly new to c++ programming, sorry if my question is too dumb)

Comment: @EyezzeyE It's simply that unrestricted pointer use is considered bad style, because it leads to many bugs.

Answer (score 0):

you are using not inited pointer of vector and that's the problem.

```
struct Mesh_Data
{
    std::vector <glm::vec3*> vertices;
    std::vector<glm::vec3*> faces; // you used a pointer to vector
};    

he::Mesh_Data* meshData = new he::Mesh_Data;
glm::vec3* test = glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);
meshData->faces.push_back(test); // faces is a stack object and push_back is allowed
```